# Such is the way of American policymaking in health care

Tags: grammar

why did we use "Such" here ? is there any alternate to this sentence?

Comment: Why do we use "such" where?

Comment: just edited the question, sorry for confusion

Comment: Downvoter: this is a legitimate and interesting question.  Yes, native speakers know what "*such*" means, but it would still make an interesting and enlightening answer if one of our more informed and academic users could elucidate the grammatical role and justification of "such" in *such sentences*.

Comment: I kind of know its answer, but in dilemma what is in my mind .

Comment: @Iamnikhil08 In this case, "*such*" means "*that is*", which also provides the alternative you asked for: "*That is* the way of American politics".

Comment: Thank you. i was also thinking something like that. but you expressed it. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *such* has a definition that is:

> Of the type previously mentioned.

So *such* would refer to what you just talked about before. For example:

> Congress has passed so-and-so laws. Such is the way of American policymaking in healthcare.